# Is there a size limitation on create2 bytecode field?

Tags: solidity, assembly, opcode, create2

I have the following method in my Solidity contract.

```
function deploy(bytes memory bytecode, uint _salt) public payable returns (address){
    address addr;

    assembly {
        addr := create2(
            callvalue(),
            add(bytecode, 0x20),
            mload(bytecode), 
            _salt 
        )

        if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }

    emit Deployed(addr, _salt);
}
```

The method works if my bytecode is 2000 characters long and the contract is deployed. But when the bytecode gets 10000 characters long the contract is not being deployed and the revert is being called. Is there a limit for bytecode size of create2?

Comment: There is a hard 24KB limit on contract size. The CREATE2 implementation of go-ethereum only checks against that limit for example : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c52def7f114aa48f50ed9956bc9661550300addb/core/vm/evm.go#L470
Nothing specific to CREATE2 as far as I know of. Are you sure about your sizes ?

Comment: Yes. But maybe as noted in the answer. I am using the full bytecode not the creation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any problem deploying a contract using the `create2` if you are able to compile your code. There is a maximum contract size limit of 24KB. Check out [this](https://blog.polymath.network/solidity-tips-and-tricks-to-save-gas-and-reduce-bytecode-size-c44580b218e6) or [this](https://dev.to/mudgen/ethereum-s-maximum-contract-size-limit-is-solved-with-the-diamond-standard-2189) if that's the issue.

you should be using creationCode and not runtimeCode. check [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/units-and-global-variables.html#meta-type) for more info.

Try running this example on [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to test How to [Precompute Contract Address with Create2](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/create2/). Add your contract and Update the `TestContract` with your contract name (`type(YOUR_CONTRACT_NAME). creationCode` ) and `_foo` with your contract constructor arguments in `getByteCode` function.

```
function getBytecode(address _owner, uint _foo) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
    bytes memory bytecode = type(TestContract).creationCode;

    return abi.encodePacked(bytecode, abi.encode(_owner, _foo));
}
```

This code will revert if you try to deploy the same bytecode with same salt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to get the creation code dynamically. Do you know how I can get it from the compiled file?

Comment: When you compile a contract, the creation bytecode is generated for you. A truffle-generated ABI refers to the creation bytecode as bytecode. This is also the bytecode that is shown when clicking “compilation details” for a contract on Remix.

Comment: In Hardhat artifact `bytecode` is creation bytecode and `deployedBytecode` is runtime bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to solve the problem. It turned out that I did not add the constructor parameters. After I added them the contract was deployed.